# giving custom argument vlue in 'q' variable

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

**also posted on druapl.stackexchange
 https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/150500/giving-custom-argument-vlue-in-q-variable
**

apologies if question is ambiguous . the scenario is as follows:

in drupal 7 , we want to use  a custom template page when a specific value is given for the `q` variable in url .

for example if we give `http://localhost/drupal/?q=xyz/123`   , we want to use a custom template page say `page-xyz.tpl.php` ..

have a hunch that hooks and template.php file may be the key components here but not sure what to exactly do..

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you could implement theme_preproccess_page() (or node, or html) to control this in your template.php

```
function YOURTHEME_preproccess_page(&$vars) {
    if (isset($_GET['q']) && $_GET['q'] == 'xyz/123') {
       $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page_xyz';
    }
}
```

that should work, but I would like to recommend not use the '?q=xyz' solution, but do an preproccess that should work to all your pages, like this.

```
function YOURTHEME_preproccess_page(&$vars) {

    $title = strreplace(' ','_', $vars['node']->title);
    //if you use the transliteration module, instead of strreplace
    //use transliteration_get($vars['node']->title);

    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page_'.$title;
}
```

now that should work for every page that you want to make a custom template. Just add the file and clear the chaches. If you don't have the page template to the specific page, it's ok, drupal will use the default.